# AngularJS filter an array of objects by text input depending on what select option is chosen

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filtering

I'm having trouble getting a particular Angularjs filtering setup working that involves a text input, ng-repeat and a select, and love any assistance anyone 
can provide.

I have an array of objects like so:

```
[{ id: '1', firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Charlston' }, ...]
```

I'm filtering the array by text input like so:

```
<input ng-model="searchText" />

<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter : searchText" ...
```

Currently, this sorts the array of people objects for "any" property value and it works fine.

What i'm trying to achieve is be able to change the property that my `<input ng-model="searchText" />` filters the people array by, based on what `<option id="1" label="lastName" selected>Last Name</option>` is selected.

My select looks like this:

```
<select class="filterSelect"
        ng-model="selectedPropertyOption"
        ng-options="prop.name for prop in peopleProperties"></select>
```

peopleProperties looks like this:

`$scope.peopleProperties = [{id: "1", name: "firstName"}, ...];`

So instead of typing: "charles" in the input and getting results that match either property id, fistName or lastName, I need to be able to choose an option from a select where the option is a property name like "firstName", that I want to filter by. Then, whatever is typed in the input would only filter objects based on which option was selected.

I hope this makes sense enough! Any guidance would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: can u please provide a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those times where it's inconvenient and kinda "dirty" (although possible) to specify the filter purely in the View.

What we need is a filter object that can take the following forms:

```
$scope.filter = { firstName: "foo" };

// or
$scope.filter = { lastName: "foo" };

// or - to reset the "filterBy" property
$scope.filter = { $: "foo" }; // or just "foo"
```

This isn't easy to do in the expression, so it's better to do in the controller:

```
$scope.filter = {$: undefined}; // initial non-filtering value

$scope.setFilter = function(){
  $scope.filter = {};
  $scope.filter[$scope.selectedPropertyOption || '$'] = $scope.searchText;
};
```

Then, invoke the `setFilter` function on every change of `searchText` of `selectedPropertyOption`:

```
<input ng-model="searchText" ng-change="setFilter()" />

<select ng-model="selectedPropertyOption"
        ng-options="prop.name as prop.name for prop in peopleProperties"
        ng-change="setFilter()">
  <option value="">All Fields</option>
</select>

<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter: filter">
  {{person}}
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MlyxZXIkC7msPInBsjqk?p=preview)**

Comment: Brilliant! I can't give enough +1s, that works exactly like I was hoping for, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: it is amazing! it is possible to have an explanation for this line: $scope.filter[$scope.selectedPropertyOption || '$'] = $scope.searchText;         Thanks